# Post to wall in .NET on Facebook (The message ,that is sent, is empty)

Tags: .net, facebook, oauth

I read [this documentation](http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/) and used the code that is given there. Everything is working fine except the message I tried to send. The message seems empty on the wall.

The accessUrl is correct so the message is sent.

```
SendHttpRequest(accessUrl, "message = This is a test", HttpMethodsEnum.POST);
```

**This is the method I used**

```
 public virtual string SendHttpRequest(string Url, string Request, HttpMethodsEnum MethodType = HttpMethodsEnum.POST)
    {

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
        string responseData = "";

        webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = MethodType.ToString();
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "[You user agent]";
        webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

        if (MethodType == HttpMethodsEnum.POST)
        {
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

            try
            {
                requestWriter.Write(Request);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                requestWriter.Close();
                requestWriter = null;
            }
        }
        StreamReader streamReader = null;
        try
        {
            streamReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            streamReader = null;
        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

Comment: Took 1 from your post because you didn't come back to end the story. SO litter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `"message = This is a test"` is the proper format for a post parameter.  Ensure that with your language that this is correct. I think the format is more complicated.  See http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx